# Why is Perl 6's loop variable declaration in the outer scope?

Tags: loops, for-loop, raku

In Perl 6, a variable declared in the for-style `loop` is in the outer scope. This works and [is documented](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/loop).

```
loop ( my $n = 0; $n < 3; $n++ ) {
    put $n;
    }

say "Outside: $n";
```

The `$n` is visible outside of the block:

```
0
1
2
Outside: 3
```

Is there a motivating trick here that makes this different from what one would expect from Perl 6's ancestors? I didn't see a mention of this in the design docs (but try searching "loop" sometime). I couldn't come up with an example where this would make things easier.

In Perl 5, the same thing is a strict error:

```
use v5.10;
use strict;

for ( my $n = 0; $n < 3; $n++ ) {
    put $n;
    }

say "Outside: $n";  # Nope!
```

And, in C (those that let you do this), it's a similar error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   for( int a = 10; a < 20; a = a + 1 ){
      printf("value of a: %d\n", a);
   }

   printf("value of a: %d\n", a);  /* Nope! */

   return 0;
}
```

As usual with my questions, I'm not interested in workarounds. I know how to do those.

---

As I noted in the comments, [Synopsis 4](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/perl6/specs/master/S04-control.pod) pushes the implementation to declare lexicals only inside the block where they will appear.

The `$n` appears before the `{` so it's not "inside" the block.

However, what about pointy blocks?

```
-> $a { put "a is $a" }
```

And, subroutine signatures?

```
sub ( $a ) { put "a is $a" }
```

These variables are first typed before the `{`.

I don't particularly care about this but if I have to explain this break with tradition by saying that you have to declare lexical variables in the blocks where you will use them, someone can point out these cases.

Comment: "This works and is documented"? I cannot see such leaking be described in any way so it might be undefined behavior.

Comment: It's documented: "The initializer is execute [sic] once and any variable declaration will spill into the surrounding block."

Comment: Fixed the [sic] in the doc, thanks for spotting!

Comment: The relevant design docs is [Synopsis 4](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/perl6/specs/master/S04-control.pod) which by fiat says "no implicit blocks", with some unconvincing justification in [Apocalypse](https://perl6.org/archive/doc/design/apo/A04.html) in the para starting "Associated with block structure are the various constructs that make use of block structure."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of it as a block is what creates a lexical scope.

```perl6
if (1) {
  my $a = 1;
}
$a;  # error
```

```perl6
if (my $a = 1) {
}
$a;  # no error
```

```perl6
loop (my $a = 1; $a == 1; ++$a) {
}
$a;  # no error
```

It's just that other C-like languages special case the (C style) `for` loop, and the Perl 6 design is to have as few special cases as possible.

So if something is very useful in one place, it should be designed so that it is useable everywhere.

---

For example `-1` indexing in arrays.
Rather than just having `@a[*-1]` as special syntax constrained to array indexing, `*-1` is just a way to create a lambda/closure that you can use anywhere you want a simple lambda.

Another example is pointy blocks being more than just a way to declare the iteration variable(s) in a `for` loop.

```perl6
for @a -> $value {…}
```

They are usable with any similar construct.

```perl6
if $a.some-resource-expensive-op -> $result {…}
```

Instead of

```perl6
{
  # note that $result isn't read-only like it is above
  my $result = $a.some-resource-expensive-op;
  if $result {…}
}
```

You can even use it as just another syntax to create a lambda.

```perl6
@a.sort: -> $value {…}
```

---

In order to make the language simpler to reason about, special cases need to pull their own weight, and having only the arguments of the `loop` construct, and no other construct, be part of the block just doesn't.
If it were generally useful then it would be different.

Also the `loop` construct is one of the few features that doesn't really fit with the general design aesthetic of Perl 6. I think it might be easier to argue for its deprecation and removal than for it to be more special cased.
(no one is arguing for it to be removed)

Comment: "doesn't really fit the general design aesthetic" is generally my feeling.

Comment: @briandfoy The design of Perl 6 can be considered [*strangely consistent*](http://strangelyconsistent.org/). Once you realize how a particular feature is consistent with another, it makes it much easier to remember, even with the necessary strangeness that makes it slightly different.

Comment: It's not rememberability that I care about so much as extrapolation.

Comment: On further thought, I think Perl 6 is inconsistent here, or at least documented incorrectly. Pointy block parameters and subroutine signatures declare lexical variables outside of the block. Those are clearly outside the block.

Comment: @briandfoy A Signature doesn't declare a variable. If you place a variable in a Signature literal `:($a)` in a lexical scope, it doesn't make the variable valid in that scope. It is the Block that takes an attached Signature and creates those lexical variables.

Comment: But that's not the point if the rule is the placement of the {.

Answer (score 4):

I see the use case in something like this:

```
loop ( my $n = 0; $n < 3; $n++ ) {
    put $n;
    last if 2.rand.Int;  # some run-time condition
}
say $n == 3 ?? 'Completed' !! 'Aborted';
```

This would be hard to do with:

```
for ^3 -> $n {
}
```

which is the `for` equivalent.

Other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think I might have tried to use a LAST phaser there to do the same thing. :)